# Show again a hide field LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

Hello everybody I am working in a LWC trying to show and hide two fields when one is filled with data the other one is hided. And if this filled field is erased the other one appears. And vice versa.
So in my .js I have this:

```
    ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido= false;
handleRazonSocial(event){
    this.razonSocial = event.detail.value;
    console.log('razon social---'+ this.razonSocial);
    if(!this.razonSocial){
        this.ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido = false;
        console.log('false');
    }
    if(this.razonSocial != null){
        this.ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido = true;
        console.log('true');
    }
}
ocultarCampoRazonSocial=false;
handleNombre(event){
    this.nombre = event.detail.value;
    if(this.nombre != null && this.primerApellido != null){
        this.ocultarCampoRazonSocial = true;
    }else{
        this.ocultarCampoRazonSocial = true;
    }
}
```

and in my .html:

```
<template if:false={ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido}>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Primer Apellido" max-length="45"  required name="primerApellido"  onchange={handlePrimerApellido}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Segundo Apellido" max-length="45" name="segundoApellido"  onchange={handleSegundoApellido}></lightning-input>    
</template>
<template if:false={ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido}>
    <lightning-input type="text" label="Nombre" max-length="45"  required name="nombre"  onchange={handleNombre}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

At the begining the fields are showed correctly but when I fill one field and erase its value to nothing the other fields does not appear.
Can anybody tell me where is the issue?
Thanks.

Comment: which field are you trying to hide?
Segundo Appellido should only show when the Primer is filled?

Comment: @JaimeGonzalez are you trying to hide one of the fields when the other has data in it? is this on input or on load you are trying to achieve this?

Comment: Hello @EliveltonWalter I want to hide Nombre and PrimerApellido when the RazonSocial field is filled, and vice versa... I mean, hide RazonSocial when the PrimerApellido and Nombre are filled. What is not working is when the user, for example erases the data in RazonSocial the other two fields does not show again.

Comment: Hello @TristanBerger I want that when the user inputs a character to hide the others 
immediately. I think I am not following you. Could you explain in other way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because the Falsy from Javascript -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

in other words lines
if(!this.razonSocial)
and the line
if(this.razonSocial != null)
are being evaluated wrong, because if the value is one of the Falsy values it will execute both statements

The first if will be true when one of these values is in it:
[image]

I would suggest the following modifications:

```js
    ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido= false;
    handleRazonSocial(event){
        this.razonSocial = event.detail.value;
        console.log('razon social---'+ this.razonSocial);
        if(this.razonSocial){
            this.ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido = true;
            console.log('true');
        } else {
            this.ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido = false;
            console.log('true');
        }
    }
    ocultarCampoRazonSocial=false;
    handleNombre(event){
        this.nombre = event.detail.value;
        if(this.nombre && this.primerApellido){
            this.ocultarCampoRazonSocial = true;
        }else{
            this.ocultarCampoRazonSocial = false;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <template if:false={ocultarCamposNombrePrimerApellido}>
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Primer Apellido" max-length="45"  required name="primerApellido"  onchange={handlePrimerApellido}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Segundo Apellido" max-length="45" name="segundoApellido"  onchange={handleSegundoApellido}></lightning-input>    
        <lightning-input type="text" label="Nombre" max-length="45"  required name="nombre"  onchange={handleNombre}></lightning-input>
    </template>
```

Comment: PS.: When I was changing the code I realize the handleNombre event is adding true all the time for the ocultarCampoRazonSocial.